# want to use it on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this code which is working well:

```
<select name="problemtype" class="survey_input" id="problemtype">
    <option value="financial">financial</option>
    <option value="legal">legal</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#problemtype").click(function(){
        $(".for_rate").show();
    });
</script>
```

However I want to use same code on a `select` option like below mentioned code. This is not working

```
<select name="problemtype" class="survey_input">
    <option value="financial" id="problemtype">financial</option>
    <option value="legal">legal</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#problemtype").click(function(){
        $(".for_rate").show();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#problemtype")` selects the element with the ID `#problemtype`. Use `$(".survey_input[name='problemtype']")` to select the element with the class `survey_input` and name `problemtype`

Comment: i want to print the select value in <a href="here"> how it is possible

Comment: @HarisFaraz I don't understand what you mean. There are no links in your example.

Comment: when above code worked correctly so the it will show a new class .for_rate as mentioned, so i want when it will show .for_rate so i want to print the result as <div class="for_rate>"result"</div>

Comment: Where is the result coming from?

Comment: <div class="for_rate">For rate...</div>

Comment: want to print this on anchor tag   <option value="financial">financial</option>

Comment: Just value Financial

Comment: Still not sure exactly what you're after. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/f7rkhn7b/?

Comment: very near you came, i want to print value in <a href="here">Not Here</a>

Answer (score 2):

Reading between the lines of your problem, what you're trying to achieve is that the `.for_rate` element is only shown when the `financial` option is selected.

If this is the case, you need to hook to the `change` event of the `select` and check the `val()` that was chosen. Try this:

```js
$("#problemtype").change(function() {
  $(".for_rate").toggle($(this).val() == 'financial');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="problemtype" class="survey_input" id="problemtype">
  <option value="financial">financial</option>
  <option value="legal">legal</option>
</select>

<div class="for_rate">For rate...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks i want to print the select value in <a href="here"> how it is possible

Answer (score 0):

in you second function you are callin on id (usind #) so you are basicly calling this row
   `<option value="financial" id="problemtype">financial</option>`

if you want to call the select either give it the id and not to the option or change the call to

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[name~='problemtype']").click(function(){
        $(".for_rate").show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i want to print the select value in <a href="here"> how it is possible

Comment: you can write $("[href~='your url']")